# Address - Polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm pretty new at Ruby on Rails and i'm not sure about using a Polymorphic Association.

I'm building a Yelp  similar application.

I have a User model and a Venue model. Both of them have one address. Is it the case to use a polymorphic association? (i'm not sure about that)

Answer (score 1):

That would be a circumstance to utilize a polymorphic association, and below is an example based on what you described.

```
class User
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Venue
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Address
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if you need polymmorphic there.
Think  first: can you solve your case if you just create `User`, `Venue` and `Address` models and then just write that User `has_one :address`, Venue `has_one :address` and Address `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :venue`.

You'll need polymorphic there if you'll want your `Address` to have `User` or `Venue` object and call them similar. I mean, you want your Address entity just have an `object` field that will reference on `User` or on `Venue`.

So, if you want to make calls like this:
`address.object.name` to get, for example, name of User or Venue that is somehow connected with this address and you **don't mind** wether it would be User or Venue, you need polymorphic. If you will need calls like `address.user.name` and `address.venue.name`, and it will be important to separate venues and users that belongs to address, you don't need a polymorphic.

Hope, I'm clear somehow...:)

Comment: In this case, i have to create a column to reference the User Model and other for the Venue Model?

Comment: @user1301037 If you mean case, when you do not need polymorphism, then yes, you have to create two reference columns. But that's not really right: you have to look at your structure, and may be you should use `belongs_through` or smth like that to prevent double- and wrong assosiations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example

```
*In student.rb file*
 class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy
end

*In teacher.rb file*
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, as: :profileable, dependent: :destroy
end

*In profile.rb file*
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
end
```

*Get the student detail by*

```
@student_detail = @student.profile.detail
```

*Get the teacher detail by*

```
 @teacher_detail = @teacher.profile.detail
```

Comment: Nice! =)

The diference between the addresses models are the latitude and longitude columns (necessary at the Venue model and not necessary for the User model). In this case what is the best approach?